# downloading images from webpage with different links

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, download, wget

I am trying to download all the images from a webpage. The images are included as follows:

How should I parametrize my wget command to specify that I only want the images where the link starts with "https://alwaysSamePart.com/"? because what follows varies avery time so I cant just specify a hardcoded link.

Ideally I should scrape all the urls af all the images out of the html code. Surf to each link individually and save each image individually.